# Media query in jquery fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, media

I'm using fancybox with **FitToView: false** to allow me to scroll inside the overlay. Everything's fine but when i resize to small devices the window does not respond like on larger devices. I wasn't able to use matchMedia with results.

here is my code, can you help me?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".fancybox-effects-d").fancybox({

            fitToView: false,
            padding: 0,
            openEffect : 'elastic',
            openSpeed  : 150,
            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            closeSpeed  : 150,
            closeBtn  : false,
            closeClick : true,
            helpers : {
                    type : 'over'

            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26710349/1055987 if that helps

Comment: When i used the "maxWidth" attribute to 90% i saw it resized a bit, but when i stretched my window it remained that big. Then I tried to add "100%" value, and still happened the same...but I accidentally closed the fancybox and re-opened it while I was on "mobile size" and surprisingly noticed that it fit perfectly (the fancybox doesn't resize in real-time at the smallest size but I didn't know). So yes in a way it helped me a lot! And I can say that you just have to put **maxWidth: "100%"** to solve the problem. It just don't scroll inside on real phone but even the body.
Anyway great,thanks.